# What will be the input to reducer without combine phase in map reduce .

Tags: mapreduce

I am reading tutorial for mapreduce with combiners 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/map_reduce/map_reduce_combiners.htm

The reducer receives the following input  from combiner

```
<What,1,1,1> <do,1,1> <you,1,1> <mean,1> <by,1> <Object,1>
<know,1> <about,1> <Java,1,1,1>
<is,1> <Virtual,1> <Machine,1>
<How,1> <enabled,1> <High,1> <Performance,1>
```

My doubt is what if I skip the combiner and allow mapper to pass the output to 
the reducer without performing any grouping operation ( without using combiner ) and allow it to pass through shuffle and sort phase .

what input will the reducer receive after mapper phase is over and after going through shuffling and sorting phase ?

Can I check what input is received for reducer ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the output your looking at from that tutorial is perhaps a bit wrong. Since it's reusing the code from the reducer as the combine stage the output from the combiner would actually look like:

```
<What,3> <do,2> <you,2> <mean,1> <by,1> <Object,1>
<know,1> <about,1> <Java,3>
<is,1> <Virtual,1> <Machine,1>
<How,1> <enabled,1> <High,1> <Performance,1>
```

In this example, you can absolutely not use the combine and the final result will be the same. In a scenario where you have multiple mappers and reducers, the combine would just be doing some local aggregation on the output from the mappers, with the reduce doing the final aggregation.

If you run without the combine, you are still going to get key based groupings at the reduce stage. The combine will just be doing some local aggregation for you on the map output.

The input to the reduce will just be the output written by the mapper, but grouped by key.

Comment: I think in the above example in tutorials point the reducer runs twice if we use combiner . Once to perform grouping and again to emit the output . I used system.out .println in reducer code and saw the output in logs . Initially it performed grouping <what  1,1,1> and then reducer emits <what 3> . The result is same for mapreduce with and without combiners .

Comment: This is incorrect `Once to perform grouping and again to emit the output`. A combine operation runs on the output of the mapper, this is usually going to be a subset of the values for a given key, they haven't been shuffled and sorted. Only once a reduce runs are you guaranteed to have all of the key/value pairs for a key. Thus a combiner in this case can do some up-front aggregation to reduce the amount of data sent over the network, and the reduce then runs to finish the job off.

Comment: I mean to say that reducer plays the role of combiner as well as reducer .  Initially in the for loop of reducer it performs summation of words which gives combiners output <what,3> and then this output is taken as input for reducer phase . Now the val.get for <what,3> will give 3 and the same is emitted by reducer as final output .

Comment: Yes it does for sure. When you start writing more complex jobs, you'll need to bear in mind that a combiner can't always be used. I've also anecdotally found that unless a combiner reduces the amount of data a pretty significant amount, say over 25%, they can have a negative effect on execution time.

Comment: reducer runs twice once to play role of combiner and once to play role of reducer agreed ? if there is no combiner <what,1> will be sent to reducer thrice consuming the bandwidth . to overcome this  combiners are used .

Comment: Now my doubt is fully cleared after reading the documentation . The output of each map is passed through the local combiner (which is same as the Reducer as per the job configuration) for local aggregation . Inside each map phase , reducer code is run locally and finally the result of all mappers are aggregated  in reducer . Here is the link . https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html

Comment: Good stuff. I'd appreciate an upvote and answer acceptance if you're sorted out.